# SSIS ETL Package Execution Issues

Tags: ssis, msbi

I have a SSIS package where excel files are uploading to the target SQL Server db.

The DFT executes inside a for each loop container as files are coming in random basis. The successful files processed and moved to Success folder and unprocessed files moved to Failed folder. But in such cases even the files processed and moved to success folder but the data actually has not been uploaded into target table. How to resolve such issues please do reply me with a fruitful solution.

Comment: You need to find a file where this has happened and you need to reproduce the issue and inspect the logs. Work out if it is file specific or some other reason. You should also try and find the logs for an already failed file

Comment: Yes this question is too general with none of the details needed to solve it.   Look at it in the debugger and tell us what's happening.